# Disk space not "sticking"

Tags: disk

I've been beating my head against the wall over here... ha. Okay, so I:

1. Create a 20GB persistent disk with CentOS 6.
2. Create an instance with "existing persistent disk" (`w/ kernal gce-v20130603`) which has an image on it... so it boots fine.
3. When I ssh into it (using putty) and check hdd space (`df -h`) I get the standard 10GB.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/u3IJmmU.png]

As you can see, when I check the instance I see the disk I made... 20GB but Linux reports 10.

Do I need to fdisk and make the volume bigger (to it's 20GB)?

Comment: Who is Kevin and why are you thanking him?

Comment: There was a space, didn't br that line... I'm sure you understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**df(1)** gives you the size of the *file system* on the partition, not the size of the partition itself.

Have a look at **/proc/partitions**, and see if the sizes are different there.

**resize2fs(8)** will resize Linux ext filesystems, **xfs_growfs(8)** will do so with XFS file systems. In default mode, they will grow the file system to fill the partition. There's no need to invoke **fdisk(8)**.